# PEFT QLoRA training on Llama 2

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, large-language-model, llama, peft

This is a more conceptual question. I am trying to perform PEFT QLoRA on Llama 2 specifically on imdb movie review dataset. I am using only 650 samples for training and 650 samples for testing. I have used "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf" model as my base llama 2 model. after i train with SFTTrainer, i save the model to a directory. If i am not mistaken only the adapter weights are saved to the directory and not the entire model weights. After doing this I know that these adapter weights can be loaded in conjunction with the original model weights using.

```
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(
    model,
    "./my_dir",
)
```

After doing this we are supposed to merge these adapter weights to the original model with

```
merged_model = model.merge_and_unload()
```

However when i perform inference with this merged_model I notice that the performance is very poor, where as the inference on just the PEFT loaded model i.e. from

```
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(
    model,
    "./my_dir",
)
```

is ideal. Is this behaviour expected? I am running inference like this

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf")
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map="auto",
)

sequences = pipeline(
    prompt,
    do_sample=True,
    top_k=10,
    num_return_sequences=1,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    max_length=500,
)
for seq in sequences:
    print(f"Result: {seq['generated_text']}")
```

Is there anything i can do better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not merging the lora weights with the base model correctly.
As shown here: https://github.com/huggingface/peft/blob/main/examples/conditional_generation/peft_lora_seq2seq.ipynb

```
config = PeftConfig.from_pretrained(peft_model_id)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(config.base_model_name_or_path)
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, peft_model_id)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(config.base_model_name_or_path)
```